# Find out how many messages sent per chat

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have seen that iPhone users of WhatsApp are able to see how many messages have been sent / received in one specific chat. This feature seems to be lacking on Android though. Am I missing it or is it simply not there?

Are there any alternatives to find out how many messages you and someone else have sent eachother?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*There's an App for that*

[WhatStat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidappetizers.whatstat) provides you with enormous amount of statistics with respect to each user.

- Overview screen that depicts messages in numbers
- Most active day of the week
- Most active time of the day
- Conversation starter percentage
- Message distribution
- History (Group by day/week/month/custom)

Need Root access after latest WhatsApp update

Comment: I'd like to note that this answer doesn't work anymore with the stopping of whatstat

Comment: http://www.groupwizeapp.com does the same as WhatStat and more! Works on Android and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be a stupid way, but it has worked for me at times.

First, email yourself your chat history. There you will get an email attachment (text file). Using any text editor (I used notepad++), find for the recipients name and see how many of their name pops up. The number would indicate how many times that recipient has send a message.

I'm sure this is actually easy to implement automatically (like an app, or a webservice), but I think it'll be more convenient just to wait Whatsapp does it for us.

Comment: I have thought about this, but instead of doing it the *hard" way, I could maybe write a script that just reads the whatsapp database file. But I just don't get why it's possible on iPhone and not on Android, seems like a simple thing to achieve...

Comment: Well, if you go by the translation files of Whatsapp, you'd notice that there are many features that are different between Whatsapp clients. It will *usually* eventually make it to the others, but considerable delays are usually there.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend a feature in what’s app which can project the message counter for individual and group chats. I have tried this manually & below is the procedure for the same.
1.  Export the chat log from a group or an individual contact.
2.  Save the document in MS Word format and perform a search using “Find” function.
3.  The keyword for the search should be the specific contact name. This gives the count of number messages sent by a contact in a group or individual chat

However, in the above scenario count will be projected based on “keyword (contact name)”. The overall count is based on number of times the “keyword” is found in the entire chat log. Although there is scope of generating the count based on respective contacts which might need further insight for retrieving the contact based relevant results.
I presume that below method can be applied to achieve the automation for same.
1.  Formulate a search function with a “keyword”, “start date” & “end date”.
2.  Keyword – What’s app contact name or number
3.  Start date & End Date-  To set up the range of the output.